# Filling not closed PathGeometry to the bottom

Tags: wpf, fill, pathgeometry

Suppose I have `PathGeometry`, consisting of **lines**, like this
(the rectangle == panel, for example `Grid`):
[image: Examples]
I want to fill them to the bottom of the panel, like this:
[image]
The quick and not very good solution I see is to create additional curve with 2 additional points in the bottom and use it for filling.

Is there some better way to solve the task?
Something like this (pseudocode):

```
 <Path Data=... FillStyle = "ToTheBottom" Fill="Blue"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard way of doing this; there is no Fill like this defined in WPF.

You could put two path geometries on top of each other. The bottom one would have a stroke thickness of 0 and has 2 extra points (those on the lower edge of the rectangle)

The second one the top would simply be the geometry you have now.

If you need to draw a lot of these you might create a custom control that does this for you.